# getById() returns undefined Promise

Tags: node.js, promise, sequelize.js, models, chai

I have the following class method in my Sequelize model:

```
getById(id) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          var Conference = sequelize.models.conference;
          Conference.findById(id).then(function(conference) {
              if (_.isObject(conference)) {
                  resolve(conference);
              } else {
                  throw new ResourceNotFound(conference.name, {id: id});
              }
          }).catch(function(err) {
              reject(err);
          });
      });
  }
```

Now I want to test my method with chai. But now when I do `Conference.getById(confereceId)` I get the following back:

```
Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }
```

Is this right and how do I assert the result of it with chai?

Comment: Take a look at [`chai-as-promised`](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Conference.getById(confereceId)` call returns a promise, so you should resolve the promise first via `then`, and assert the result of it with `chai` like this:

```
const assert = require('chai').assert;

Conference
  .getById(confereceId)
  .then(conf => {
    assert.isObject(conf);
    // ...other assertions
  }, err => {
    assert.isOk(false, 'conference not found!');
    // no conference found, fail assertion when it should be there
  });
```

Comment: If any of the assertions in the `then()` fail, they would also trigger the `catch()`, which can cause confusing errors.

Comment: Thats true, I edited the answer to use `.then(onFulfilled, onRejected)` rather than `.then(onFulfilled).catch(onRejected)` to address this issue.

Comment: Yeah I saw, +1 :D